# find the total mass in the segment $[1,2]$ at the time $t=60$.

Tags: calculus

A problem in Differential Calculus :

Assume that the initial density of a matter along the $x$-axis is given $p(x)=e^{-x} $kg/m. if the mass moves with the constant velocity $v=10m/s$ in the direction x-axis, find the total mass in the segment $[1,2]$ at the time $t=60$.

I need to take classes in my PhD and I have forgotton these concepts completely
Can someone help please?

I know Density=Mass/Volume
How can I use velocity in this problem?
Can someone give some hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motion means that you want the mass in an interval of length $1$ that moves to be at $[1,2]$ at time $t=60$ (presumably seconds).  You are to integrate the density over that length to get the mass.

Answer (score 0):

First, account for time dependence of the density. If at $t=0$ you have $p(x,0)$ and the mass moves in the positive direction, it means at time $t$, you have the mass distribution $p(x,t)=p(x-vt)=e^{-(x-vt)}$.

The second thing to notice is that this is a linear distribution (not volume), so you can write than the formula for mass $$m=\int_1^2p(x,t)dx$$

Comment: So I need to compute $\int e^{600-x} $

Comment: But the answer is not coming

Comment: What do you mean? You already have an answer and it's not what you expect?

Comment: I checked with my textbook ,it shows a different answer

Comment: Educated guess: your problem is wrong.